# Apply the border property to pdfkit in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit, content-tag

I need to generate the pdf with pdfkit and content_tag. its working fine, now i want to add the page border property to the page. 
I tried to add the (border_style: 'solid' or border_width: 5), this got error pipe line broke error.
could please any one help me to how add the page border-property.

Comment: PDFKit.configure do |config|
config.default_options = {
:page_size => 'Letter',
:margin_top => '0.5in',
:margin_right => '0.5in',
:margin_bottom => '0.7in',
:margin_left => '0.5in'
}
end

Comment: The above code i am used pdfkit.rb. applying all properties fine , but i am unable to apply border property . thanks